# Reuse fragment structure and passing complex arguments

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, bundle, android-alertdialog

I have implemented a DialogFragment class which shows a dialog and call a custom listener when its button is pressed.

Since I want to reuse this class in many projects I need to pass the listener when I create the fragment. However I don't know how I could do it.

I know I should not pass the listener in the constructor because Android could call the default constructor if it has to recreate the fragment and I cannot pass the listener via Bundle arguments because Bundle does not support it.

The unique solution I found is make the activity implement the custom listener and check it in onAttach method. The problem is that this way would limit the implementing classes to the owner activity and maybe it does not fit to the application.

Does you find a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You normally have a static `newInstance()` method to create your fragment and pass in any values your fragment might need. That's the method to pass your listener to.

Have a look here where a `newInstance()` method is also used as an example:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: I think question was how to restore all listeners when android recreate fragment.

Comment: Don't think so. The question explicitly mentions that the constructor is not usable. But maybe I'm wrong. Let's wait for Urizev's comments.

Comment: Both of you are right. The constructor is not usable and I need to restore the listeners when android recreate the fragment. The base problem is that I need to pass custom objects to the fragment and the mechanisms I know are not enough.

Comment: This answer is not valid for me. I need to be sure that the listener is properly passed when recreated. I do not care if it is done by Android automatically or by me manually.

Comment: I agree, that it's not the solution for your problem. I guess your onAttach approach is the best solution. You could also let Activities pass arbitrary listeners in to your fragment in their onAttachFragment method, but this is way too brittle for my liking.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's not possible. I read the doc over and over and I don't find a right solutions. They suggest the onAttach solution so I will take that but I'm not happy. :(

If you wanna edit your solution with that comment I mark as accepted.

Thanks!!

Comment: @Urizev why don't you try passing the listeners as Parcelable objects, using the newInstance() method of course. AFAIK you can pass any object as Parcelable, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Jose_GD Yes, you could but the listener could be an Activity, a Fragment which could not be parcelables. Even more, when you pass an object as a Parcelable the listener object is copied so the original listener wouldn't receive the notifications.